# Excel Events not working

Tags: excel, event-handling, vba

I have a macro that creates a workbook from another workbook with events. I have created a custom workbook class called eventWB to add the events. This works great, except when I close the new workbook created and re open it, the events dont work. I tried adding the following function to the ThisWorkbook file for the new workbook but it does not seem to enable the events. I added an alert to make sure the function is working and it works great. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Function in ThisWorkbook:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Newbook As New eventWB
Set Newbook.Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set Newbook.m_events = Application
Set thisWB = Newbook.Workbook
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A quick fix that I can think about is to catch it in the Private Sub Workbook_Activate(), also, why did you took out Private in the Sub Workbook_Open?

Comment: Hello @Sgdva thank you for your quick reply, I tried your solution and unfortunately it did not work. I took out the private thinking as a public method it might work.

Comment: hmm could there be that another process is enabling events false? Why enable events is set to true if it shouldn't be off in the first place?

Comment: Hello @Sgdva sorry for the delay, I have buttons on the macro that turn it off but upon completing the function they turn them back on, however i  am not clicking on anything when the excel page opensm, also this buttons are added on a module so there shouldnt be any interference?

Comment: Hello @Sgdva thank you for guiding me in the right direction. I ended out creating a function in the module that sets the variables it uses and enabling events, and had the Workbook_activate call it at start and it works! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by adding a function on the module im using:

```
Function reopenResetVariables()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Set Newbook.Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Newbook.m_events = Application
    Set thisWB = Newbook.Workbook
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

and adding call reopenResetVariables to the Workbook_Activity function when opening excel